# Why is the substr(...) not doing what I want it to do?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a piece of code where I'm generating a preview of the job listings on my site. It should be pretty self-explanatory, but I'm trying to get the first 100 characters of a column of type `VARCHAR (5000)` in my database.

```
            $Jobs = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM jobs');
            foreach ($Jobs as $thisJob)
            {
                // use first 100 characters of job description before a "Read more" link to the full description
                echo  ' <div class="job-row">'
                      .   '<h3 class="job-title">' . $thisJob->title . '</h3>'
                      .   '<div class="job-descr-brief">'
                      .        substr($thisJob->descr, 100) . ' <a href="' . get_site_url . '/about/careers/?jobid=' . $thisJob->id . '">Read more.</a>'
                      .   '</div>'
                      .'</div>';
            }
```

For some reason, however, `substr($thisJob->descr, 100)` is returning the full `$thisJob->descr` string, not just the first 100 characters. Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Relevant documentation: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_substr.asp

Comment: `string substr ( string $string , int $start [, int $length ] )` http://php.net/substr

Comment: You want to use `substr($thisJob->descr, 0, 100)`. Always use the php.net manual, not w3schools, just for the future.

Comment: It seems odd, though, that the function call in the sample code is apparently still outputting the full string, without removing the first 100 characters.

Comment: Ah, wait a minute:  is $thisJob->descr less than 100 characters long AND you are running a version of PHP before 5.2.2?  The version comments in Charlotte Dunois' link say:
"5.2.2 - 5.2.6 If the start parameter indicates the position of a negative truncation or beyond, false is returned. **Other versions get the string from start.**"

So, I think you may be running an older version of PHP and are putting in a parameter longer than the length of the contents of the field, so it doesn't truncate it at all.

Comment: @dspitzle Are you sure about that. I just ran https://3v4l.org/9bukd which runs the script against like 150 versions of php and all produced the same output, `false`.

Comment: @dspitzle And just checked this: https://3v4l.org/aNKk1, which shows that only applies to negative values. It is a little odd, but when they say "beyond" I believe they mean starting from the end of the string, moving backwards, "beyond" the start of the string. So a 5 character string, -6 or less.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you misread the documentation.

You need to use it like this to get the first 100 characters:

`substr($thisJob->descr, 0, 100);`

The second parameter is where you want it to start (in this case 0, the beginning).